# Passing MySQLi object to function

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

So I'm making a login system for a web app I'm developing. I have a `register.php` file, which is NOT a class. I have an `AccountInterface.php` file, which is a class.

> register.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]))
{
    header("http://ezblog.guru");
    return;
}
require_once("../api/AccountInterface.php");
require_once("../api/Utils.php");
use Massively\api\AccountInterface;
$accountAPI = new AccountInterface();
$creds = parse_ini_file("../../config/mysql.ini");
$conn = new mysqli($creds["ip"], $creds["username"], $creds["password"], $creds["db"]);
var_dump($conn);
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    echo "MySQLi connect error:" . $conn->connect_error;
} else
{
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === $email)
    {
      if(!filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
      {
        if(!$accountAPI->checkAccount($username, $conn))
        {
            if(!$accountAPI->accountExists($username, $email, $conn))
            {
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?:($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']?:$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
                $salt = Massively\api\Utils::random_str(40);
                $pin = rand(10000, 99999);
                $accountAPI->registerAccount($username, $email, hash_pbkdf2("sha512", $password, $salt, 27000), $ip, $salt, $pin, $conn);

                $msg = "$username,\nThank you for registering an account with E-Z Blog. Before you get started writing blogs using our beautiful web application, please confirm your e-mail by visiting ezblog.guru/confirm.\nYour pin code is $pin\n/E-Z Blog";
                $msg = wordwrap($msg);
                $headers = "From: ezblog@gmail.com <E-Z Blog>";

                //mail($email, "EZ-Blog - confirmation", $msg, $headers);
                return;
            } else
            {
                echo "This Email address is already taken";
                return;
            }
        } else
        {
            echo "This username is already taken";
            return;
        }
      } else
      {
        echo "Please make sure your username is not an e-mail address";
        return;
      }
    } else
    {
        echo "Please enter a valid Email address";
        return;
    }
}
?>
```

> AccountInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Massively\api;
class AccountInterface
{
  public function checkAccount($user, $conn)
  {
    if($conn instanceof mysqli)
    {
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username=?;");
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      if($stmt->num_rows === 0)
      {
        $stmt->close();

        return false;
      } else
      {
        $stmt->close();

        return true;
      }
    } else
    {
      return "!instanceof mysqli";
    }
  }

  public function accountExists($user, $email, $conn)
  {
    if($conn instanceof mysqli)
    {
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username=?;");
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      if($stmt->num_rows !== 0)
      {
        $foo = "!user";
      } else
      {
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE email=?;");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows !== 0)
        {
          $foo = "!email";
        } else
        {
          $foo = false;
        }
      }
      $stmt->free_result();
      $stmt->close();

      return $foo;
    } else
    {
      return "!instanceof mysqli";
    }
  }

  public function getUser($email, $conn)
  {
    if($conn instanceof mysqli)
    {
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE email=?;");
      $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      if($stmt->num_rows === 0)
      {
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();

        return false;
      } else
      {
        $stmt->bind_result($user);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
          $foo = $user;
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();

        return $foo;
      }
    } else
    {
      return "!instanceof mysqli";
    }
  }

  public function registerAccount($user, $email, $password, $ip, $salt, $pin, $conn)
  {
    if($conn instanceof mysqli)
    {
      if(!$this->accountExists($user, $email, $conn))
      {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (username, email, password, ip, salt, pin, verified) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssii", $user, $email, $password, $ip, $salt, $pin, 0);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        return true;
      } else
      {
        return false;
      }
    } else
    {
      return "!instanceof mysqli";
    }
  }

  public function unregisterAccount($user, $conn)
  {
    if($conn instanceof mysqli)
    {
      if($this->checkAccount($user, $conn))
      {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM accounts WHERE username=?;");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        return true;
      } else
      {
        return false;
      }
    } else
    {
      return "!instanceof mysqli";
    }
  }

    public function getPin($user, $conn)
  {
    if($conn instanceof mysqli)
    {
        if($this->checkAccount($user, $conn))
        {
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pin FROM accounts WHERE username=?;");
          $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->store_result();
          $stmt->bind_result($pin);
          while($stmt->fetch())
          {
            $foo = $pin;
          }
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();

        return $pin;
        } else
        {
          return false;
        }
    } else
    {
      return "!instanceof mysqli";
    }
  }

    public function login($user, $password, $conn)
  {
    if($conn instanceof mysqli)
    {
      if($this->checkAccount($user, $conn))
      {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username=? AND password=?;");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows === 0)
        {
          $foo = "allowed";
        } else
        {
          $foo = "!allowed";
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();

        return $foo;
      } else
      {
        return false;
      }
    } else
    {
      return "!instanceof mysqli";
    }
  }

    public function getSalt($user, $conn)
  {
    if($conn instanceof mysqli)
    {
      if($this->checkAccount($user, $conn))
      {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT salt FROM accounts WHERE username=?;");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($salt);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
          $foo = $salt;
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();

        return $foo;
      } else
      {
        return false;
      }
    } else
    {
      return "!instanceof mysqli";
    }
  }

  public function setVerified($user, $conn)
  {
    if($conn instanceof mysqli)
    {
      if($this->checkAccount($user, $conn))
      {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET verified=? WHERE username=?;");
        $stmt->bind_param("is", 1, $user);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        return true;
      } else
      {
        return false;
      }
    } else
    {
      return "!instanceof mysqli";
    }
  }

    public function getVerified($user, $conn)
  {
    if($conn instanceof mysqli)
    {
      if($this->checkAccount($user, $conn))
      {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT verified FROM accounts WHERE username=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($verified);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
          $foo = $verified;
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();

        return $foo;
      } else
      {
        return false;
      }
    } else
    {
      return "!instanceof mysqli";
    }
  }

  public function getUserObject($user, $conn)
  {
    if($conn instanceof mysqli)
    {
      if($this->checkAccount($user, $conn))
      {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, email, ip FROM accounts WHERE username=?;");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $email, $ip);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
          $foo = new Account($id, $user, $email, $ip);
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();

        return $foo;
      } else
      {
        return false;
      }
    } else
    {
      return "!instanceof mysqli";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

All the functions I call with PHP return "!instanceof mysqli", and even if I remove the `if($conn instanceof mysqli){}`, nothing happens to the db. However, if I add a `var_dump($conn)` anywhere in `register.php`, I get that it is a `mysqli` object. I'm assuming `$conn` isn't getting passed to the `AccountInterface` function correctly? What can I do to solve this?

#### EDIT:

I know that `$accountAPI->checkAccount($username, $conn)` returns `"!instanceof mysqli"` because I added `if($accountAPI->checkAccount($username, $conn) === "!instanceof mysqli"){ echo "not an instance of mysqli"; }`, which outputted `not an instance of mysqli`. I didn't show this here because I wanted to show my original code.

#### EDIT 2:

After fidgeting around a little bit with the `checkAccount` function, I added a `var_dump($stmt)`, turns out `$stmt` is an instance of `mysqli_stmt`, yet nothing is being done to the db still.

Comment: This is probably not the only problem, but it's a start. Instead of returning `"!instanceof mysqli`, just return `false` and see how the behavior changes.  Because you are executing it as `if(!$accountAPI->checkAccount($username, $conn))`  even when an invalid, non mysqli object is passed, the _string_ error message you returned is going to be a true value.  That doesn't sound like the same error you described, but it is definitely not correct in and of itself...

Comment: To debug why nothing changes in the db, you should check errors on the MySQLi object.  `if (!$stmt) { echo $conn->error; }`  I don't see it in the posted code, but it is possible that `$conn` got overwritten or closed at some point. If that's the case, it would be `null` and fail your check.

Comment: It's a little misleading to name a `class`  as `AccountInterface`. I had to read it over to understand that it's indeed a `class` and [not an `interface`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I added a `if($accountAPI->checkAccount($username, $conn) === "!instanceof mysqli"{}`, and the code inside the brackets ran. I removed it from this to show my initial code. I'll edit the post to include that though.

Comment: So, I added a `var_dump($stmt)`, turns out `$stmt` is an instance of `mysqli_stmt`. Yet nothing is done to the db still

Comment: I think, you need to start by learning how to actually use dependency injection. And object-scope variables. But that would just be the first step, because, as your code is now, it's a damned mess.

Comment: @tereško I know it is, this isn't gonna go in production, it's just an opportunity to learn. I asked this question to learn how to do it correctly, so I actually am "learning how to actually use dependency injection" and whatnot by asking this.

Comment: You're using namespaces, so try `$conn instanceof \mysqli`.

Comment: Since all of your methods need the DB connection, why don't you  write: `__construct(\mysqli $connection) {$this->connection = $connection; }`

Comment: @ccKep Thanks, the code inside `checkAccount` now runs, however nothing is executed in the db

Comment: `checkAccount` only `SELECTs` stuff, nothing is supposed to change there.

Comment: I meant when `registerAccount` is called, but I just realized I never asked about that in my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve it by actually applying dependency injection. Your code would look kinda like this:

```
namespace Massively\api;
use MySQLi;

class Authentication
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(MySQLi $connection) 
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }


    public function checkAccount($user)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username=?';
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        // ... etc.
```

And in your `register.php` it would look like:

```
$conn = new \MySQLi($creds["ip"], $creds["username"], $creds["password"], $creds["db"]);
$accountAPI = new \Massively\api\Authentication($conn);
// some unimportant code here

if(!$accountAPI->checkAccount($username)) {
    if(!$accountAPI->accountExists($username, $email))
    {
        // more code here
    }
}
```

And you really need to work on naming things.

Comment: And yes, I'm still learning all the naming conventions and the subtle differences between things

Comment: You can try watching this lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHBrDWIKW8Q ... it might help a bit.